# Modify content inside quotation marks, BASH

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Good day to all,

I was wondering how to modify the content inside quotation marks and left unmodified the outside.

Input line:

```
,,,"Investigacion,,, desarrollo",,,
```

Output line:

```
,,,"Investigacion, desarrollo",,,
```

Initial try:

```
sed 's/\"",,,""*/,/g'
```

But nothing happens, thanks in advance for any clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic awk way to do this is simply:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {sub(/,+/,",",$2)} 1' file
,,,"Investigacion, desarrollo",,,
```

or if you can have more than one set of quoted strings on each line:

```
$ cat file
,,,"Investigacion,,, desarrollo",,,"foo,,,,bar",,,

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) sub(/,+/,",",$i)} 1' file
,,,"Investigacion, desarrollo",,,"foo,bar",,,
```

This approach works because everything up to the first `"` is field 1, and everything from there to the second `"` is field 2 and so on so everything between `"`s is the even-numbered fields. It can only fail if you have newlines or escaped double quotes inside your fields but that'd affect every other possible solution too so you'd need to add cases like that to your sample input if you want a solution that handles it.

Comment: It's also more robust, faster, briefer, and clearer. It will work with text between the commas outside of the quotes (try all solutions with `,,save_me!,,"Investigacion,,, desarrollo",,,` as input :-) ), and you don't need to add a loop populating variables to work on one at a time if you have a multi-line file or stream for input. This really is THE way to solve this problem using standard UNIX tools.

Comment: Good day Ed Morton, Indeed your proposal is the best one! But I kept trying with your script and I got stuck on the following example: `,,save_me!,,"Investigacion,,, desar,,,rollo",,,`, I got: `,,save_me!,,"Investigacion, desar,,,rollo",,,`. Would be too much of me if I ask you how to handle this new system? Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Alejandro - just change the `sub()` to a `gsub()`. `sub()` works on the first occurrence of an RE in a string, `gsub()` works on every occurrence of an RE in a string.

Answer (score 3):

Using a language that has built-in CSV parsing capabilities like `perl` will help.

```
perl -MText::ParseWords -ne '
    print join ",", map { $_ =~ s/,,,/,/; $_ } parse_line(",", 1, $_)
' file
,,,"Investigacion, desarrollo",,,
```

[Text::ParseWords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html) is a core module so you don't need to download it from CPAN. Using the `parse_line` method we set the delimiter and a flag to keep the quotes. Then just do simple substitution and join the line to make your CSV again.

Answer (score 2):

Using `egrep`, `sed` and `tr`:

```
s=',,,"Investigacion,,, desarrollo",,,'
r=$(egrep -o '"[^"]*"|,' <<< "$s"|sed '/^"/s/,\{2,\}/,/g'|tr -d "\n")

echo "$r"
,,,"Investigacion, desarrollo",,,
```

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if there's one tool that can do everything that egrep+sed+tr+pipes can do so there's a less AWKward solution.... ;-).

Comment: perl can do that in one line without running a loop like awk

Comment: Is a brief, clear and simple loop a bad thing? Also, not every UNIX installation has perl (I don't have it and can't install it on the production machines I use at work, for example) and it's not tagged in the question. Having said that, I'd be interested in seeing the perl solution if you care to post it.

Comment: I don't code in `perl` but here is what I could come up with as perl one liner: **`perl -pe 's#("[^"]*")#sub { $x=$1; $x =~ s/,{2,}/,/; return $x; }->()#eg' <<< "$s"`**

Comment: Yeah, that's about what I thought it'd look like :-). Give me a simple loop any day. Isn't `-p` the perl instruction to run a script in a loop anyway?

Comment: I forgot the important thing - thank you for posting that perl solution I asked to see!

Comment: @EdMorton `perl` has a CSV parsing module that can make it easier on the eyes. `:)`

Comment: @EdMorton: You're most welcome, sorry my `perl` awareness is very limited. jaypal's is much better person on perl-fu here.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ p = ""; while (match($0, /"[^"]*,{2,}[^"]*"/)) { t = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); gsub(/,+/, ",", t); p = p substr($0, 1, RSTART - 1) t; $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH); }; $0 = p $0 } 1'
```

Test:

```
$ echo ',,,"Investigacion,,, desarrollo",,,' | awk ...
,,,"Investigacion, desarrollo",,,
$ echo ',,,"Investigacion,,, desarrollo",,,",,, "' | awk ...
,,,"Investigacion, desarrollo",,,", "
```

Comment: @Alejandro [Ed Morton's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25144925/445221) is most appropriate.